# Font Awesome is displayed as a question mark on Macbook Pro. Any ideas on how to fix this (see pics)?

Tags: macos, font-awesome

It's really weird, but for some reason when I try to install FA as a font on my system, it displays all the icons as a square with a question mark in it. Have a look:

[image]

Even after installation, it's the same:

[image]

The strange thing is, FA icons display fine in my browser, as long as they are

Anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: have just came across this same problem myself, rather perplexing. Noticed it whilst trying to get FontIcons running for Sketch. ++Following

Comment: Ah man! Same here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally! I found an answer for this over at the [fortawesome github issues](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/10068#issuecomment-253889991). It's as simple as installing the font, ignoring the question marks, and then using the [fontawesome cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) to copy and paste the icons in your document.

I'm so glad I found an answer to this! I didn't even think of trying to just copy and paste the icons after installing the font.